# How to save entire scrollable canvas as PNG?

Tags: perl, image, canvas, png, tk-toolkit

I have a scrollable canvas who's content i want into a png image.

The problem is I only get a photo of the canvas, missing the non visible part of the canvas at that given time.

How do i get the whole scrollable canvas into a png image?

My current code is the following:

```
my $canvas_to_get_photo=$mw->Photo(-format=>'Window', -data=>oct($canvas_to_get->id));
$canvas_to_get_photo->write('somepath/image.png', -format=>'png');
```

Comment: Could you create example images (what you got and what you need)? Last one as montage, of course.

Comment: its just a canvas which you can scroll, which means only a part of it is visible at a time. when i print the canvas i only see the visible part, not the part that's hidden because the user hasn't scrolled to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a native way to do it; Tk only paints to windows, not to image-based surfaces. Your options are therefore to either:

1. scroll the canvas, taking snapshots, and then stitch them together
2. generate encapsulated postscript (which *does* support going over the whole canvas, provided you use the right options) and generate your image from that with a tool like ghostscript.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a awhile since I did any heavy [Tk](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/) work, so this may not work.  Have you tried looking for the non-scrolled subcomponent of the scrolled canvas.

IIRC, each 'Scrolled' widget is actually a "mega-widget", with scrollbars, a corner item, and a scrolled item sub-widgets.

So, it may be that you want

```
my $canvas = $scrolled->Subwidget('widget');
$canvas = $scrolled unless $canvas;
my $canvas_id = $canvas->id;

my $photo = $mw->Photo(-format => 'Window', -data => oct $canvas_id );
$photo->write('somepath/image.png', -format => 'png' );
```

Comment: doesn't work, it still just prints the visible part of the canvas.